# Is this 'off' also an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

In this example sentence:

> He needs more time **off** duty for relaxation and rest.

the Longman dictionary says that *off* in the given example is an adverb. If the sentence was:

> "He needs more time off,"

I would understand that *off* is an adverb. But in this case, *off* is followed by a noun, *duty*. Is this *off* also an adverb?

From [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/off_1):

> **off**
>   5 not at work, school etc because you are ill or on holiday: 
>   *He needs more time off duty for relaxation and rest*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [online OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130593#eid33835453) has a separate entry for *off-duty*, which can function as an adverb, a noun and an adjective. It is made up of the preposition *off* and the noun *duty*. In your example, it is perhaps best seen as an an adjective postmodifying *time*.

Comment: Yes - _off duty_ is more cohesive than _off school_, say. But 'it' would be written as two orthographic words if used in the predicative position. _Off work_ is a less ambiguous-to-analyse example; the compound _out-of-work_ exists, but not, I think, _off-work_.

Comment: Would you consider the *at work* in *time at work* to be an adjective post-modifying *time*? I think the prepositions in these cases are just that: prepositions.

Comment: @Robusto: No. I think _off-duty_ is a special case. But I agree that it can be analysed in more than one way.

Comment: It's sometimes almost meaningless trying to reason by analogy with equivalent-looking expressions that seem more readily analysable. In _He went off_ (_He went off right after the end of the play_ sounds totally acceptable), _off_ is certainly not an adjective (as it undoubtedly is in _The cheese is off_). I think that the only near-acceptable thing to do is to put these whatsits into a separate class. Those doing so usually call the class particles, but put such disparate elements (such as the infinitive-marker _to_, the negativiser _not_) into this new class they're re-inventing the adverb.

Comment: @Robusto: Can you give a reference that would allow multi-word (as opposed to hyphenated-compound) adjectives? I certainly think that some multi-word constructions are best treated principally as single lexemes (eg ship of the desert, spick and span). I've seen the term 'adjectival' used for 'any expression doing the job of an adjective' - ie used for the superset - eg in 'The Grammar Plan Book'; Weaver - but it has confusingly differing usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm not saying those constructions are never adjectival. In "We discussed his *at-work* performance," clearly *at-work* functions as an adjective. But when it comes after the noun it does not seem so clearly an adjective, and arguments for that seem rather strained and twisted. As for reasoning by analogy, isn't that what you would call the grouping of like constructs for similar analysis? We put these things into bins and then label the bins. I give you Twain on the subject: "It were not best that we should all think alike; it is difference of opinion that makes horse-races."

Comment: Unfathomable. But the question was not meant to be incisive - I'm struggling to find support for the concept of 'multi-word adjectives' in line with open compound nouns: _particle board_ (one of the three permitted forms!) is **a compound noun** and hence **a noun**!

Answer (score 4):

You've come across a much-debated, and probably still-unresolved, part of English semanto-syntactic (meaning + grammar) analysis here, Listenever.

The authors of CGEL would doubtless say that the usages of *off* in

*He needs more time off.*

and

*He needs more time off work / school / duty. ...*

are so similar that they should not be put into different classes. They use the traditional term **preposition** for the second usage, where *off* fulfils the syntactic role of relating the occupation 'he' needs to be resting from to the first part of the sentence (*He needs more time*), as well as meaning 'away from'. They use the term 'intransitive preposition' (not their coinage) for the usage which assumes the hearer can easily fill in the unstated occupation mentally.

However, Cappelle, in [this paper](http://stl.recherche.univ-lille3.fr/sitespersonnels/cappelle/Pdf%20versions%20of%20papers/The%20particularity%20of%20particles.pdf), argues in my opinion convincingly that this particular (no pun intended) lumping of word-classes is erroneous.

Comment: +1 for the Cappelle. It’s an exaggeration to say that any English word can serve as any part of speech; but in these cases I see no reason not to say that these are prepositions acting as ... What? They’re compounded with verbs, nouns, &c: postfixed, but semantically bound like Latin preposition prefixes, and in some degree “separable”, like German preposition prefixes. Would “proxifix” serve?

Comment: _Proxifixes_ will be a dustbin-class within weeks.

Comment: It would at least be a somewhat smaller and more manageable dustbin. *Secondary component of a phrasal verb*?

Comment: All Part-Of-Speech tagsets (from [Donatus's original Eight](http://www9.georgetown.edu/faculty/jod/texts/donatus.4.html) -- _Partes orationis quot sunt? Octo. Quae? Nomen pronomen verbum adverbium participium coniunctio praepositio interiectio._ -- to the latest [Universal Set](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/2843/482), are just collections of prototypes, with lots of loose change and grey areas among them. Grammar is not [A Big Bag Of Words](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/003299.html). Little words are the problem, usually.

Comment: **I've struck gold!**  [English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-rule.htm):         Preposition Rule

There is one very simple rule about prepositions. And, unlike most rules, this rule has no exceptions.

Rule: A preposition is followed by a "noun". It is never followed by a verb. // **So there!** (This will keep me laughing over Christmas.)

Comment: I think you're getting a little sliver of H&P wrong there. And it's not H&P, it's Jespersen, really. There is no need for any nouny thing to be missing or inferred from preposition phrases. There's just no need at all for a noun. It's just the case that many prepositions do happen to take nouns. It's not that the preposition label's wrong because some prepositions are exceptional. It's just that, like verbs, prepositions may take complements  - or not! :) [PS first misread your post, so  please ignore my entirely erroneous comment if you read them!]

Comment: Like Cappelle (and many others), I do not consider Jespersen's lumping sound. So I'm going to say 'There is a need for a noun'; it's as valid as the alternative, and the traditional view.